# Windows 7 stuck at log in screen

Tags: windows-7

Recently installed fresh Windows 7. I installed updates and restarted computer to apply changes, then i connected my usb mouse to this laptop and after restart, touchpad and keyboard is not working but this mouse is working and i can interact with everything with it.

I tried restarting, but nothing. 
Then i tried to log in Safe mode to disconnect usb device from cmd but there was this same problem.
What can i do

Comment: Windows typically requires a driver for the touchpad to be functional.  If you connect an external keyboard does that work?  Without a better understanding of what updates got installed during that first phase of updates this will be tough to answer.  I can almost guarantee you all the updates that are available were not installed at once.

Comment: Yes, i installed some additional updates after first update and it was called "Update for windows 7 for 64-bit based system"

Comment: I am a little confused. The title says "Windows 7 stuck at log in screen" but then you say "this mouse is working and i can interact with everything with it". Can you rephrase to something?

Comment: Sure. I set password so every time i turn on the computer it is showing log in screen and there i can interact with password field, shut down button, keyboard switch. So when mouse is connected it can interact with everything but keyboard and touchpad is nof working. Also cursor is blinking in password field

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. If anyone has this problem-your keyboard and/or touchpad is not working and you are stuck at log in screen

1. Click on Ease of access button in the lower left corner
2. Check "Type without the keyboard"
3. Type in your password

   Next you want to go to your laptop manufacturer website and search for appropriate drivers and download them.